# django URL reverse: When URL reversig a username it fails when username has a '.' literal in it

Tags: python, django, url, reverse

I didn't expect this to occur [since I didn't know when django changed to allow _ and . in usernames], but when I attempt
{% url feed_user entry.username %}

I will get a 500 error when the username contains a '.'
In this case rob.e as a username will fail.

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem will be in whatever regex you are using in your urls.py to match `feed_user`. Presumably you are using something like `r'(?P<username>\w+)/$'`, which only matches on alphanumeric characters and doesn't match on punctuation.

Instead, use this: `r'(?P<username>[\w.]+)/$'`

Comment: This fixed it! Totally didn't think about that.  Thanks Daniel